# Stretch TextView to fill remaining space after displaying ImageView fixed to bottom

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to implement a layout where an `ImageView` is fixed at the bottom of the screen with a TextView placed right above that stretches to fill the remaining vertical space with the text centered in its bounds. Now the image should never scale up beyond its original size bit it should scale down when needed to ensure the `TextView` is always fully visible. The image may be taller than a device's viewport especially in landscape. That's the tricky part.

I've gotten close to this layout with a root `LinearLayout` and applying `layout_weight`s but this is not sized using the image's size, therefore the image is scaled inappropriately based on the weight and screen size. With a little more thought I was able to fix the image to the bottom, ensure it doesn't scale up but does scale down while ensuring the text is fully visible, but the text does not stretch vertically to fill the available space - it's sized based on the text content therefore it's always fixed at the top.

How can this layout be achieved?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/text_1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/textview_1" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/my_tall_image_1"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:id="@+id/imageview_1" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following updated xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/myimage_1"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:id="@+id/imageview_1" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_above="@id/imageview_1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/text_1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/textview_1" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope it will work for you :)

Comment: Thanks Neo, this works well in portrait but in landscape the image is not scaled down, therefore the text is not visible as the image's height is set to `wrap_content`.

Comment: For this you have only one option to fix the maxHeight of your imageView as per your requirement (let say 100dp or 150 dp). So that it will not go beyond your specified area,

Comment: The height of the ImageView should be dynamic, up to the full height of the image but auto scale down if the available height is not tall enough to fit the TextView and the full-height image.

Comment: Then better to set maxHeight only.